# How do you find the changesets between two tags in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, changeset

If I have two tags named 2.0 and 2.1, how do I find the changeset messages between the two? I'm trying to find to a way to use HG make release notes and  list the different messages associated with the commits.

Example Changeset:

`changeset:   263:5a4b3c2d1e
user:        User Name <user.name@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Nov 27 14:22:54 2018 -0500
summary:     Added tag 2.0.1 for changeset 9876fghij`

Desired Output:

`Added tag 2.1 for changeset 67890pqrst
Change Info...
Added tag 2.0.1 for changeset 9876fghij
Change Info...
Added tag 2.0 for changeset klmno12345`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface**

"Any challenge has a simple, easy-to-understand wrong decision". And Boris's answer is a nicest illustration for this rule: "::" topo-range will produce good results *only* in case of pure single-branch development (which is, in common, **The Bad Idea (tm)** anyway)

**Face**

Good solution *must* correctly handle complex DAGs and answer on question "New changesets included in NEW, missing in OLD (regardless of the nature of occurrence)"

For me it's "only()" functions in revsets with both parameters

> "only(set, [set])"
>
> Changesets that are ancestors of the first set that are not ancestors
>   of any other head in the repo. If a second set is specified, the
>   result is ancestors of the first set that are not ancestors of the
>   second set (i.e. ::set1 - ::set2).

```
hg log -r "only(2.1,2.0)"
```

maybe for better presentation powered by predefined style "changelog"

```
hg log -r "only(2.1,2.0)" -s changelog
```

or custom style|template

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a revset to select all changesets between two tags, for example: `2.0::2.1` will likely do the trick. You can validate the selected changesets by running: `hg log -G -r '2.0::2.1'`. (See `hg help revset` for more information about revsets).

Once you have the right selected changesets, you can now apply a template to retrieve only the needed information. For example if you only want the first line of changeset description, you can do `hg log -r '2.0::2.1' -T '{desc}\n'` for the whole description or `hg log -r '2.0::2.1' -T '{desc|firstline}\n'` only for the first line of each changeset description.

If you want to add even more information, `hg help template` is your friend.

Comment: Indeed, the topo-range works only for single-branch development and Lazy Badger answer is better suited.